# Why is "Hash Sum mismatch" when installing nodejs on vagrant box ubuntu/bionic64

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I'm newbie of using Vagrant. Recently I have an project required Nodejs version 12.x, I decided start with vagrant project, but unfortunately getting trouble while installing. I using the same installation command for normal Ubuntu VM created by ISO file it working. Below are the bash command for installation and error message I get.

**bash command**

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x  | sudo -E bash 
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

**Error**

```
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_12.18.3-1nodesource1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:546d5fd658be511f0568e2744b73eca3f04eb1b155491ff7bc0ffb373aa69bce
    - SHA1:ca9a7a04d0a8e01b8ec27f583185df234f89819a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:266488f3f4f8b9c82e92a57b2dd01048 [weak]
    - Filesize:18166022 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:33f571ecd7e761bbbd9445f47778a0f0a351a415e42ea12683865131c0ed922c
    - SHA1:b9363f314bbc2fc820542b1a28e27b395c60d4af [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7464ea66e911ef8817c5abf653468837 [weak]
    - Filesize:18166022 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 18:28:18 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried to follow this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) here to troubleshooting, but not working.

I'ii appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another newbie here. I had the same issue with nodejs 14.x and Oragle VM VirtualBox 6.1.12.

I tried to solve the issues (mongodb had the same hash issue) with removing removing /var/lib/apt/lists/*, updating with apt-get update --fix-missing, cleaning apt-get, installing different nodejs and mongodb versions, ...

**But which finally fixed my problems was downgrading VirtualBox** from `6.1.12` (latest) to [`6.0.24`](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_0). Thanks for user VivekDev [in another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972907/10349241).

After downgrading you may have issues with running virtual machines on VirtualBox. This can be solved with a `cmd` command (as an **administrator**) `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`. Restart PC and try again `vagrant up`.

Comment: Thank a lot, work fine after downgrading the Virtualbox.

Comment: Actually "netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled" ran on Windows Admin command prompt fixed it for me in a faster way. Source is the same (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972907/10349241) but bit further down...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20 and i faced the same error.
i tried many things but nothing worked

finally i ran the below commands and npm was installed successfully

```
sudo su -
mkdir /etc/gcrypt
echo all >> /etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny
apt-get update
sudo aptitude install npm
```

Note : install aptitude if not already installed