# Hash Sum mismatch error, and others, while Installing Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 VM (VirtualBox)

Tags: docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

Preface that I'm running these commands on a VirtualBox VM, Ubuntu Server 18.04. Unfortunately I can't get the bidirectional clipboard to work so I have to post all the output as links. Super sorry about that.

I've been trying to install Docker on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on VirtualBox running on a Windows 10 Home, Version 10.0.19041 host. I've been encountering issues at every turn.

First, I tried to install with apt-get after following the instructions on the [Docker Ubuntu install tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), to no avail. I get [an error with "Hash Sum mismatch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xky.png) shown pretty frequently. I also tried running the convenience script (i.e. `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh` followed by `sudo sh get-docker.sh`) on a completely fresh machine, and got the same errors.

After I was unable to install with apt-get, I tried downloading the packages and installing manually. When trying to curl the packages with

`sudo curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb`

and the same curl for `docker-ce-cli` and `containerd.io` debs I'm able to complete the downloads just fine. Then, when I run

`sudo dpkg -i ./docker-ce_18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb`

to install the packages, I get [these dpkg Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACfIo.png), claiming that the deb is corrupted. I get the same errors no matter which deb I specify.

I suppose at the end of the day, Docker isn't strictly necessary for the project I'm working on, but it's  very frustrating that I'm at such a loss. I'd be very grateful if anyone can give me some guidance. Please feel free to comment if you need any more system info.

p.s. I've seen a couple theories but don't know how to address them.

- Possibly, an issue with WSL2 and the Virtual Machine Platform on Windows. [Discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027483/cant-install-docker-hash-sum-mismatch-ubuntu-18-04-vagrant-virtualbox), but it didn't seem like anyone found a solution.
- An issue related to `apt-cache` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/*`, which I've already cleaned cleared multiple times.
- I've also run `apt-get update` more times than I can count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update here. In the end I was unable to install Docker on my VirtualBox VM. The thing that worked for me was booting up an Ubuntu 18.04 VM in VMware. With all the same specifications, I was able to install Docker and get my application running. If anyone comes back to this question and finds a fix for this on VirtualBox, please post it and I'll mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The GCrypt so library has a real issue computing hashes when running VirtualBox or other VM software under Windows 10. I made a video about this.

https://youtu.be/inU8pQLXIkE

Here is the solution:

```
mkdir /etc/gcrypt
touch /etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny
cd /etc/gcrypt
sudo vi hwf.deny
```

(edit this file to read "all" without quotes on line 1
Save.

This will solve the issue.